# Converting Date to UTC

Tags: ruby

I have a Date without Time. How can I covert it to UTC so that it'll look like this `1431561600000`? I know how to do that for Time but not for Date without Time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have time, timestamp would be created for `00:00:00` localtime by default:

```
date = "18 April 2015"
Date.parse(date).to_time.utc.to_i
# => 1429295400
```

Also as `.to_i` generates Unix epoch time, `.utc` does not mean much here:

```
Date.parse(date).to_time.to_i # Time.now.zone => "IST"
# => 1429295400
```